# Displaying and counting inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
A=0
T=0
while True:
    number = input("Input an integer or 'Q':")
    print()

#Quit program if Q or word beginning with q is input
    if number.lower().startswith("q"):
        print("Quit",'\n'"Total",'\n',T)
        break
#run program sum inputs

    elif number.isdigit():
        A = A+1
        T += int(number)

#if A input display inputs and total inputs sum

    elif number.lower()=="a":
        print(A,'\n' "total",'\n',T)
        break

#iF T input calculate inputs sum#

    elif number.lower()=="t":
        print("Total"'\n',T)
        break
#if not integer or display message

    else: #number.isalpha():

        print(number, "Invalid input")
```

When I run `A` it doesn't give me the inputs just the number of inputs. How do I get it to print all the inputs? Same also if I leave the input box empty, I am getting invalid input. Why is this?

Comment: It pritnts the input. add '\n' before the 'A':
`print('\n Inputs: ',A,'total:',T)`

Comment: while thanks for that, I don't need it to print the string "inputs" what i need is: it to list the inputs i entered, i.e 1,2,3,10,15  total 31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding of your code, it looks as though you only increment a variable A every time you put an input in. If you want a list of inputs, I suggest somethings like this:

Before while loop:

```
list_of_inputs = []
```

During while loop:

```
elif number.isdigit():
    list_of_inputs.append(number)
```

Then you can print this list of inputs later, simply by adding:

```
elif number.lower() == "t":
    print (list_of_inputs, "\n", "total\n", T)
```

Also, you get an invalid input when you enter nothing, because you don't pass any of your if statements. Nothing is neither "a", nor "t", nor "q", nor a digit. Hope I answered your questions.

Comment: Thanks very much, that helped a lot.